# Get all users based on Profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there any way to select all users based on their Profile settings?  I am using the default implementation of Profiles in C# MVC2.

Something along the lines of this

```
var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
return View(users);
```

But with a Profile select would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with based on MEYWDs link

```
var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();

List<MembershipUser> searchResults = users.Where(user => Profile.GetProfile(user.UserName).CustomerID.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(CustomerID.ToLowerInvariant())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the profile for a user using

```
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(username);
```

Then you can just search for specific profile settings with `profile.GetPropertyValue`

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough.  I want to select all users with a specific profile.GetPropertyValue.  I could grab all users then loop through and check the values on by one with profile.GetPropertyValue, but that seems incredibly inefficient since we have thousands of users.  Is there a more efficient way to do this inside Membership or Profile?